# database implementation of data having M:N relation

Tags: database, database-design, database-schema

I have to create a database having only 2 tables student and course. There is no relation between them or say atmost 1 relation is acceptable. 
Query that usually runs on it :-
"Get courses registered by a student".
So it should be quick to respond. Please tell how to implement such database?

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENT 
(student_id INT PRIMARY KEY)

CREATE TABLE COURSE 
(course_id INT PRIMARY KEY)

CREATE TABLE COURSE_REGISTRATIONS 
(
student_id INT,
course_id INT,
)
```

In `COURSE_REGISTRATIONS`, the `{student_id, course_id}` combination is the primary key, and obviously `student_id` and `course_id` are foreign keys to their respective table.

You can query `COURSE_REGISTRATIONS` for the information you need.